# Different Kmean results by sklearn and from scratch

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

I tried to compare the kmean clustering result from `sklearn` package and from scratch. The scratch code is showns below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style

style.use('ggplot')
import numpy as np

colors = 10 * ["g", "r", "c", "b", "k"]


class K_Means:
    def __init__(self, k=3, tol=0.001, max_iter=300):
        self.k = k
        self.tol = tol
        self.max_iter = max_iter

    def fit(self, data):

        self.centroids = {}

        for i in range(self.k):
            self.centroids[i] = data[i]

        for i in range(self.max_iter):
            self.classifications = {}

            for i in range(self.k):
                self.classifications[i] = []

            for featureset in data:
                distances = [np.linalg.norm(featureset - self.centroids[centroid]) for centroid in self.centroids]
                classification = distances.index(min(distances))
                self.classifications[classification].append(featureset)

            prev_centroids = dict(self.centroids)

            for classification in self.classifications:
                self.centroids[classification] = np.average(self.classifications[classification], axis=0)

            optimized = True

            for c in self.centroids:
                original_centroid = prev_centroids[c]
                current_centroid = self.centroids[c]
                if np.sum((current_centroid - original_centroid) / original_centroid * 100.0) > self.tol:
                    print(np.sum((current_centroid - original_centroid) / original_centroid * 100.0))
                    optimized = False

            if optimized:
                break

    def predict(self, data):
        distances = [np.linalg.norm(data - self.centroids[centroid]) for centroid in self.centroids]
        classification = distances.index(min(distances))
        return classification

kmeans = K_Means()
kmeans.fit(reduced_data)

for centroid in kmeans.centroids:
    plt.scatter(kmeans.centroids[centroid][0], kmeans.centroids[centroid][1],
                marker="x", color="b", s=169, linewidths=3, zorder=10)

for classification in kmeans.classifications:
    color = colors[classification]
    for featureset in kmeans.classifications[classification]:
        plt.scatter(featureset[0], featureset[1], marker="o", color=color)

plt.show()
```

However, the results are different due to the different converged centroids.
The scatter plot from sklearn:
[image]

While, the scatter plot from the code above:
[image]
I am wondering what mistakes within the scratch code.

Comment: please include full code.
NameError: name 'reduced_data' is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

K-means is highly dependent on initialization conditions i.e. the starting point for the means. scikit-learn can do smart initialization based on the data. You can probably configure scikit-learn's version to match your own if you read the documentation carefully. Also, try looking at the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0fb307bf3/sklearn/cluster/_kmeans.py#L749) for more clues.